# Is there a way to get the generating function of Hermite polynomials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, special-functions

I would like to know if there is any physical model in which the generating function of the Hermite polynomials arises, I know the problem of the quantum harmonic oscillator but I have not found the generating function there.
In my notes, the function I am referring to is the following
\begin{equation}
G(x,t)=e^{-t^2+2tx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
where $H_n(x)$ are the Hermite polynomials, I am interested on the exponential form.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am looking for the standard form of the generating function of Hermite polynomials

Comment: I have edited the question, adding the equation I need

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am looking for examples of the derivation of generating Hermite function, like Legendre Polynomials and electric dipole's problem

Comment: I believe this is the shortest, most elegant derivation that exposes the *logic* of the generating function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition) of Hermite polynomials,
$$G(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}  
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!} (-)^n e^{x^2} \partial_x^n e^{-x^2} \\
\bbox[yellow]{=e^{x^2} e^{-t\partial_x} e^{-x^2} = e^{x^2}e^{-(x-t)^2}  }=e^{-t^2+2tx}.
$$
The operator series has been summed to a formal exponential, which is precisely [Lagrange's shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Definition), yielding the standard expression directly (yellow).

Note that
$$
(\partial_x^2 -2x\partial_x +2n )H_n =0 ~~~~\leftrightarrow ~~~~(\partial_x^2 -2x\partial_x +2t\partial_t)G=0.
$$

Is this what you want?

- If you were comfortable with the above, you could segue to the celebrated [Mehler kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel#Physics_version) that your textbook probably covers if it's any good...