# Deriving recurrence of the Hermite polynomials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-functions

I am trying to follow Sakurai in Modern Quantum Mechanics, 3rd Ed., Section 2.5.  We define the Hermite polynomials as

$$  g(x,t)\equiv e^{2xt-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2xt-t^2)^n}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2x-t)^n\,\frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)\,\frac{t^n}{n!} $$

Somehow, the Hermite polynomials replace a function of $x$ and $t$ with one of just $x$!  The $n=0$ term is equal to one for any exponential series so $H_0(x)=1$.  I differentiate the left and right hand sides to get

\begin{align}
\underline{\text{RHS:}}\qquad\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty H'_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}~~.\tag{1}
&\,\\&\,\\
\underline{\text{LHS:}}\qquad\qquad\qquad~~~~~\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}g&=2tg\\
&= 2t\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}\\
&= 2t\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}\\
&=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)} \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}\\
&=2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)H_n(x) \frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\quad\text{let $~ m=n+1$}\\
&=2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty mH_{m-1}(x) \frac{t^m}{m!}~~,\tag{2}
\end{align}

It follows from (1) and (2) that

$$  H'_n(x)=2nH_{n-1}(x)~~.  $$

Sakurai says this is good enough to start generating the polynomials.  I start with

\begin{align}
\int\!dx\,\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}H_1(x)=2\int\!dx\, H_0(x)\\
H_1(x)=2(x+c_0)~~,
\end{align}

but I cannot determine the constant $c_0$ and, therefore, I cannot proceed.  What has Sakurai done here to determine the integration constant?  (page 100, 3rd Ed.)  I've seen some of the other StackExchange questions about this that have been posted before but they all look very complicated compared to what Sakurai has done.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599783/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-generating-function-of-hermite-polynomials).

Comment: Thanks but I think the answer to that question uses the recurrence relation $(\partial_x^2 -2x\partial_x +2n )H_n =0 $ which I have not derived yet.  It takes the recurrence relation as a starting point but Sakurai proceeds without deriving or using it.  If I cannot proceed without this (I think Sakurai skipped a step) then how can I derive it from scratch?  However, Sakurai (or Napolitano) said it's not needed so I don't know if he is or is not right about that.

Comment: No, that answer *derives* that recursion. In any case, I'll write an answer.

Comment: Thanks, you are a cool guy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ g(0,t)= e^{-t^2}= \sum_m {(-t^2)^m \over m!}= \sum_n H_n(0) {t^n\over n!} \leadsto \\  
 H_n(0) = \begin{cases} 
 0 & \text{for odd }n, \\
 (-2)^\frac{n}{2} (n-1)!! & \text{for even }n.
\end{cases}
$$
So you have the values at 0 pegged.

So $c_0=0$, the next constant $c_1=-2$, the next vanishes, etc....

---

*Edit in response to @WhyMeasureTheory comment*

For the even powers, *n=2m*, since the odd ones vanish,
$${(−)^(2)!\over !}=(−2)^ ~(2−1)!!=(−2)^{/2}(−1)!!$$

Comment: Nice and clean, thanks a lot.

Comment: I know it's super late, but could you explain how you compare the coefficient of $\frac{t^n}{n!}$ from both side? @CosmasZachos